# How to calculate the difference in days between dates that are numeric?

Tags: excel, date, numbers, difference, days

The dates are in a number format, what can I do? I tried the subtraction in other cases for the same year, it seems to result, but when it has the case below, it delivers a result of 8874, which is not what I want (it would be 5 days what i wanted).

Example in excel:

```
A1 = 20180103
A2 = 20171229
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to using `DATEVALUE` is to use the `DATE` function, which avoids an unnecessary string concatenation then date parsing:

```
= DATE(LEFT(A1,4), MID(A1, 5, 2), RIGHT(A1,2))
  - DATE(LEFT(A2,4), MID(A2, 5, 2), RIGHT(A2,2))
```

Comment: thanks, it worked and gave me the 5 days difference, since it attended to the timeline (from 2017 to 2018)! :) have a nice day!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
=
DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,2) &  "/" & MID(A1,5,2) & "/" & LEFT(A1,4)) 
- 
DATEVALUE(RIGHT(A2,2) &  "/" & MID(A2,5,2) & "/" & LEFT(A2,4))
```

This first converts the number into a format that excel can recognise as a date, then convert it to the date, and finally deduct one from the other.

Comment: Assylias - you're right- thanks! I changed a test value and forgot to update the mid starting position! I've updated it now.